# Cómo comparar 2 valores de la misma columna

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Tengo una base dato llamda m_mis que tiene una columna llamada cue_subc, que contiene varias cuentas, y solo quiero filtrar 3131 y 3151, y en la misma bd m_mis hay otra columna con los estados de las cuentas 3131 y 3151 y a su ves tiene dos valores 01 y 02. Estás cuentas tienen personas que si están en la 3131 con estado 01, significa activa y si están en la 3151 02 significa: inactiva y quiero filtrar en una consulta esos estados.

Comment: cuando dices "tengo una vase de datos", te refieres a una tabla?

Comment: Si te refieres a una tabla llamada m_mis para filtrar debes hacer uso de un WHERE después de haber hecho la selección de la tabla.

Comment: Saludos. Tu pregunta esta mal formulada y de esa manera es dificil que algun miembro de la comunidad pueda ayudarte. Te recomiendo que leas [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).